# Change the reg.line equation (without constant) in ggscatter

Tags: r

I'm trying to visualize multiple scatter plots by region. However, I need to perform a linear regression without a constant.
How can i add the regression line without constant, and the corresponding R^2?
Below is my code.

```
ggscatter(
  reg_data, x = "PCE.Annual", y = "Annual.Increase",
  color = "Region", palette = "jco",
  add = "reg.line"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~Region) +
  stat_regline_equation(formula=y~x,label.y = .15) +
  stat_cor(aes(label=..rr.label..),label.y = 0.1)
```

Comment: Could you provide the data you are using using for instance the dput() function?

Comment: change your formula to `y ~ 0 + x`

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add **formula=y~x-1** in **stat_regline_equation** function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).